# What is the difference bewteen atomic orbitals and wannier functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, orbitals, tight-binding

They both use the "s, px , py, pz, dxy...." formalism
Both of them are in real space.
Wannier is orthogonal but atomic orbitals are not...

But what's the fundamental difference between them?

Comment: What in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wannier_function is not clear?